# How to use sinks with separate hot/cold taps?

Tags: uk, tips-and-tricks, local-customs, ireland, hygiene

I just traveled to Ireland. I was amazed to find that water sinks (at home, restaurants and public) have separate taps for hot and cold water.

If you use only the cold water, your hands freeze. If you use only hot water, your hands burn.

How do people use it?
Is there tool at plumber shops to mix both of them (for my accommodation)?

[image: Sink with separate hot/cold taps]

Comment: How is this a travel question?

Comment: Tool to mix them?  Sounds like a great product idea!

Comment: You think that's messed up... I've been to apartments in Israel where the toilet had no tank... you need to turn a valve to start flushing, then turn it back to stop the flushing.  It was cheaper for the landlord to install and maintain and the tenants tolerated it.

Comment: For a historical perspective, consider the pre-plumbing washbasin. You pour water in it, use the water for washing, then dump it. So having a way to draw hot & cold water directly in to the basin was a huge improvement! Washing your hands in running water came along much later.

Comment: I think this is an appropriate question or topic for travel.se. It's something that travellers might encounter around the world, and hence advice on this would be benefitial for travellers.

Comment: Great question! When I stumbled into these weird things in the UK, my reaction was "WTF? Worst usability ever." You either get too hot or cold water, and the taps were too far apart to use both simultaneously...

Comment: @Andra: I'd say it's a travel question in the same way as questions about [electrical adapters](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-kind-of-plug-adapter-should-i-pack-for-india)

Comment: So in what countries are separate taps unknown? Egypt, from the OP's location?

Comment: @Yousf If either taps give you the extreme of what you desire, then surely logic kicks in at some point.

Comment: My problem in the UK was not so much the dual taps -- those are pretty common around the world -- but the huge variety of not-really-working mixer taps. In one home there was one where you could adjust the temperature but not the pressure: you had a choice of blasting off your skin with cold, warm or hot water. In another, a choice between freezing cold and boiling hot (and about half a millimeter of just-slightly-too-hot in between).

Comment: I was reminded of this question when I saw [Tom Scott's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfHgUu_8KgA) explaining *why* this is so common in Britain.

Comment: @e100 I've only ever seen separate taps in the UK, but I've travelled mostly in developed countries in Europe, North America, and Asia, but not much in Commonwealth countries apart from Canada (where I've never seen separate taps).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had the same problem after arriving to the UK. There are two basic techniques:

1. Plug the sink, pour the water and wash yourself in this water. I think this was how it was meant to be used when this system was first introduced years ago. You can mix it in any other container as well, depending on your needs.  One potential downside to this method is that if the sink is not very clean you don't exactly want to be letting the presumably clean water sit in the basin.
2. Open both taps and move your hands quickly between both taps. If you do it quickly enough you almost get the water mixed :)

Why did these nations decide to use this system and why haven't they replaced it with mixer taps is a mystery to me.

Comment: You don't waste water if you plug the sink. I think of it as a smart design choice for saving the Earth.

Comment: I didn't like this "fill the sink, and wash your hand", sinks are not that clean!

Comment: I will practice more on "move you hands quickly". Hopefully I can be fast enough :)

Comment: @mouviciel, the thing is you can do the same thing with a mixer tap. And many people use option (2) mentioned above, which wastes by far the most water.

Comment: Why do they use it?  Probably a combination of resistance to change and willingness of the public to tolerate inconvenience.  I'm sure the 2 tap system is cheaper so if there's no motivation to spend more money they won't.

Comment: @JoelFan: "tolerate inconvenience" -- are you kidding me? Has it ever crossed your mind that people may not even find it inconvenient? I live in a country where both kinds of sinks are very common, and I don't find either one any more incovenient than the other.

Comment: Why would you consider sinks unclean? This is an interesting cultural difference.

Comment: @balpha: If you have been accustomed to running hot water or bathroom in your home, wouldn't you call it "inconvenient" if you go to to a place with an outhouse? But for the people living there, it sure won't be inconvenient (or they would have changed it), because they are used to it, or don't have anything to compare to.

Comment: @balpha... I'm not getting how you could find 2 taps no less convenient... you must not wash your hands that often or wash them thouroughly

Comment: They didn't replace them when mixer taps came out because mixer taps were expensive when they came out. They didn't replace them when the prices got lower because plumbers are expensive. They didn't replace them themselves because by law a plumber has to do it or they just don't want to mess up their plumbing and they're used to the old separate taps.

Comment: @hippietrail, it doesn't explain why in many new developments they would still install separate taps. And today the price difference between mixer and separate taps in negligible comparing to plumber's fees.

Comment: @Grzenio: Maybe some places are just more conservative and resistant to new ideas, even good ones?

Comment: Bloomsbury Theatre amuses me with a sign saying BEWARE THE VERY HOT WATER and old school taps. Top tip: Get in there early before the pipes are up to temperature.

Comment: @balpha I agree with your comments totally. If people find washing with a 2 tap system problematic, I dredd to think what other problems they have encountered in life.

Comment: or just get used to washing your hands and face with cold water rather than lukewarm :)

Comment: I was also surprised when I visit a friend of mine in a new house in UK, still this silly double tap, anyway it is just problematic for washing hands and face as in the shower they both go in the same showerhead.

Comment: Oh, people!  For god's sake, don't use the first "technique". Do you want to make your hand clean or dirty! Both of this so-called technique was a lot of water.

Answer (score 71):

I just found this gr8 (well, not very great) workaround. [image: work around to deal with separate taps!].

Didn't try it yet, but looks like it may work.

Comment: A thing of beauty! (And I hope you're not infringing anybody's copyrights)

Comment: regarding the copyrights, I found this photo like this, I searched for its origin but failed. full copyright and patent for the unknown photo owner.

Comment: +1 for the creativity. But wouldn't it be a problem to have hot (or very hot) water running in a plastic bottle?

Comment: @Vince The melting point of plastics used for bottles is significantly higher than the boiling point of water. No reason for any concern.

Comment: This answer fits on [Lifehacks.SE].

Comment: @Bernhard as someone who has deformed plastic by washing it in hot water, I can say that the temperature at which at least some plastics lose their rigidity is considerably lower than the boiling point of water.

Answer (score 29):

While others have answered *how*, I'll try to answer *why*:

Technology.

The hot water used to come from a hot water storage tank, usually in the attic. The stagnant water in the tank isn't considered safe for drinking. That's why there has to be a separate system, all the way down to the taps, so it can't contaminate the safe cold water from the mains (should there ever be a pressure failure or some such).

Even though water tanks aren't used that much anymore, old habits die hard.

It's [explained by Tom Scott](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfHgUu_8KgA) in the YouTube series *Things You Might Not Know*.

Comment: It disn't *use to*, it's still the same horrible piping system. I'm disappointingly surprised even after a couple of years, at how Brits and the Irish built and do build their houses in the most primitive ways even in 2016. Hygiene and convinience seems to be the last priority. Lame.

Comment: @Neeku Hygiene, convenience, and [staying alive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-35862763) are not prioritised.  Tradition is.

Comment: It should be mentioned mixer taps _are_ becoming steadily more common  as a lot of people (but not everyone) opt to install them when renovating their bathrooms. A modern combi boiler system poses no contamination risk.

Comment: Besides, if you keep a storage heater *hot* (above oh, 55 deg C) you don't pose any contamination risks either, as it'll be too hot for nastiness to grow in there anyway.  Which makes the whole separate tap system baffling to me...

Comment: "Even though water tanks aren't used that much anymore" [citation needed]. Hot water tanks are still common in the UK. I have one. For larger houses my understanding is that combi boilers aren't suitable. I have mixer taps that mix cold drinking water with hot water from the tank... it's not unusual!

Comment: @Neeku Comparing the two possible hot-water-tank systems, anecdotally I find the old "filled from the attic" system to be much more reliable than hot water tanks filled directly from pressurised mains systems. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.

Comment: @Muzer I'd like to hear your arguments on this. What is unreliable about the modern systems? Maybe the ones you've seen are not standardized.

Comment: @Neeku It's completely anecdotal, but I've known multiple different houses with modern hot water tanks fed from pressurised mains systems to end up with multiple problems requiring various plumbers, whereas I've known no such thing for attic-fed systems! It's probably not significant. And combi boilers are fine, I'm just talking about the cases where you still want a hot water tank (eg for large houses) but directly fed from the high pressure mains.

Comment: How about taking that discussion to chat, people?

Answer (score 16):

I (an Irish person) only recently found out that this was an oddity of our country.

What I do usually is either use just one (like the hot tap, but quickly) or the cold tap. It's not that cold! Or just fill up the sink

Comment: It is not typical Irish. I do have 2 sinks in my house with separate taps. I have also seen it in dozen other countries. That is why I am really surprised this question appears on travel.se and not being closed as of topic.

Comment: This is not an oddity of Ireland. I have seen this in the UK (where it is common) and in the US also.

Comment: I have only seen this in the UK, but I've mostly travelled to developed countries in Europe and North America.

Comment: @gerrit Right now, I'm sitting in a house in California that has a mixer tap in the kitchen and separate taps in the bathroom, just like my home in the UK. OK, most other places I've been in the US have mixer taps in the bathroom, too, but separate taps aren't a British-Isles-only thing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've only been in a handful of homes in North America.  Not saying they don't exist, but they're not nearly as ubiquitous (relatively speaking) as in England.

Comment: I've also seen that in France.

Answer (score 10):

Separate taps are still pretty common in Australia though mixer taps are on the rise.

What I usually do is check if the hot water is hot straight away. Usually it's not but I suppose this could depend on how the hot water is set up which may be different in Ireland.

If the hot tap is not hot straight away I use the hot tap just on just a bit checking with my fingertips every second or so if it's warm enough yet. I usually have enough time to have a good wash before the heat gets too high.

If not I prefer cold hands to any degree burns, but again I suppose Ireland sometimes has colder tapwater than Australia too (-:

Answer (score 8):

I am quite surprised at your question. Here in the UK, two single taps, one for hot water and one for cold water are the normal arrangement. You put the plug in the sink and half fill it from one tap, then you run the other into it until you have the temperature of water you want...or you do what I do, which is wash under a running cold tap.

Comment: It may be normal and fine in the UK (and Ireland etc), but still feel somewhat primitive and unwieldy for the rest of us. ;)

Comment: Not for all the rest of us. But this answer only covers clean sinks. It won't work in lots of pubs and nightclubs and many other public toilets unless submerging your hands in diluted mystery ick is not a problem or you always keep some household cleaning products with you (-;

Comment: @Jonik When you go to another country you shouldn't expect things to be the same as when you are at home. The majority of modern homes these days have mixer taps, however its doesnt take a genious to use a 2 tap system

Comment: @hippietrail you're right for the cleanliness of the public places, that's why I never wash my hands in pubs except high grade restaurant. While traveling, I often use this portable alcool bottle: http://goo.gl/KbvveR

Comment: @hippietrail Most pubs, nightclubs and public toilets in the UK these days have a combined/single tap, and an increasing number have a motion sensor so you don't need to touch anything.

Answer (score 5):

I have recently started to use the [Retromixer](https://retromixer.com/).

[image: Retromixer]

It doesn't work extremely well but it's better than nothing.  Whenever the water pressure is more than minimal, water tends to flow out along the top in addition to  the bottom.  And where it does flow along the intended bottom, the mixing isn't very good; I might get hot and cold water in rapid alteration in time and space.  But it's progress nevertheless and I recommend it.

It's rather small and easy to install, so in principle you could carry one around for usage in public places, but it's marketed for use at your own home.

(I am not affiliated with the company making the Retromixer, nor do I personally know anybody involved.)