# What kind of power plug adapter do I need in Argentina and Chile?

Tags: switzerland, electronic-items, chile, argentina, power

I'm going to Argentina and Chile and have a couple of electronic devices I want to charge. I have Swiss plugs consisting of two bolts:

[image]

What kind of adapter should I pack for Argentina and Chile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As always, Wikipedia has a good list which can answer this question. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country which has info, specs, and pictures for each plug type by country.

It looks like Chile and Argentina have different mains plug types and you may only need an adapter for Argentina.

Answer (score 7):

In Chile, ungrounded plugs are compatible with Europlugs, so you should be able to use the Swiss plug directly. Some sockets only accept grounded plugs, which have a round grounding pin directly between the two round power pins. Apparently similar plugs are used in Italy, but I had never seen an adapter for it before I came to Chile.

I have no recollection of the kind of plugs used in Argentina, even though I was there recently. My packing checklist for that trip says Type I adapter, like for Australia and China. As I had no trouble with charging my equipment, that should have been the correct adapter.

Comment: It's not like Australia, the Argentinian I type is wired the opposite way round.

Answer (score 2):

Argentina commonly uses dual plugs that fit European and Australian/Chinese plugs. Make sure that you have the Aussie plugs though as not all are dual plugs.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into getting one adapter to fit "all." For example:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=UXU&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&tbm=shop&sclient=psy-ab&q=multi+country+plug+adapter+sweden&oq=multi+country+plug+adapter+sweden&gs_l=serp.3...4415.4415.0.5067.1.1.0.0.0.0.353.353.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.32.psy-ab..1.0.0.kesUYbD2_4I&pbx=1

The individual ones can be small and easy to lose. There is some interesting insight here regarding bringing power strips:

[Should one bring a power strip when travelling from the U.S. to Europe so that one won't have to get more than one power adapter?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/should-one-bring-a-power-strip-when-travelling-from-the-u-s-to-europe-so-that-o)

Comment: Thank you for sharing with us! I had not even thought about it for my travel plans.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need a Type C or L adaptor for Chile.  Often marketed for use in Italy.

Comment: How about indicating what a type C or type L is? A new traveller wouldn't have any idea about the difference.

Comment: Type C has 2 round prongs and type L has 3 round prongs, but considering that also describes other types (that won't fit), it was helpful for me to know the exact letters when purchasing adapters on eBay before coming. Chile uses both C and L, depending on the device or socket (though a C plug fits and works in an L socket). IIRC, I was able to use my C adapters/plugs while in Argentina.