# Adapter in Koh Chang?

Tags: thailand, power

My wife and I are planning to visit a hotel in Koh Chang Thailand in January.
Does anyone know if an adapter is needed?

We are from Sweden. According to Wikipedia we use CEE 7/4, commonly called "Schuko" socket, has a recessed round shape with two symmetrical round sockets and two earthing clips on the sides of the socket.

I have heard that is depends on where in Thailand you are. This is our first time on this island.

Answer (score 5):

According to [electricaloutlet.org](http://electricaloutlet.org), the outlets in Thailand are either [type A](http://electricaloutlet.org/type-a) or [type C](http://electricaloutlet.org/type-c) outlets, respectively:

[image: type A]
[image: type C]

Type C is used in Sweden as well, along with [type F](http://electricaloutlet.org/type-f) (they are almost the same, C can fit in F and vice versa), so all you need to be certain is an **adapter from type C/F to type A** as shown above.

Regarding voltage, in Thailand it is 220v and in Sweden it is 230v, so no problems, you can use your devices from Sweden in Thailand.

Comment: You may want to look into getting one adapter to fit "all." For example:
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=UXU&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&tbm=shop&sclient=psy-ab&q=multi+country+plug+adapter+sweden&oq=multi+country+plug+adapter+sweden&gs_l=serp.3...4415.4415.0.5067.1.1.0.0.0.0.353.353.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.32.psy-ab..1.0.0.kesUYbD2_4I&pbx=1  

The singles can be small and easy to lose. There is some interesting info here regarding power strips: 

http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/should-one-bring-a-power-strip-when-travelling-from-the-u-s-to-europe-so-that-o

Comment: By far the most common outlet shape in Thailand accomodates both of the plugs pictured.   In case you do come across outlets as pictured, plug adapters are widely available for under a dollar (not transformers, which as Halabi says you don't need).

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you, I have [explained it all, at length](http://blueapsara.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/almost-electrical-convertors-adapters-south-east-asia/).