# Power outlets for passenger use in Gatwick Airport

Tags: power, lgw

Are there outlets in Gatwick Airport, specifically South Terminal, where I can charge my laptop before flight?

Are there outlets that will have standard European or North American sockets instead of the UK version? I'm just transiting through so it'd be better if I didn't have to deal with a UK adapter.

Comment: Probably best to assume that the majority of plugs will be normal UK ones

Comment: There are zero international plugs.

Comment: Apparently there's a paid-for service called Chargebox with lockable lockers for your charging devices and cables for common devices - basic info on the official site http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-services/internet-and-wifi/ and also https://www.essentialtravel.co.uk/airportparking/gatwick/airport-information/ No idea how much it costs but price varies by how long you use it

Answer (score 8):

[Stranded at Gatwick Airport: 5 Things to Do When Your Flight is Delayed](https://www.skyparksecure.com/blog/stranded-gatwick-airport-5-flight-delayed/):

> There are spare power sockets throughout both terminals that you should be able to use surreptitiously without anyone minding. Gatwick’s cafes and bars also usually have free power points. Don’t ask for permission, ask for forgiveness. If you must spend money, Chargebox operates several units airside in both terminals that let you charge mobiles from £1.50 for 30 minutes.

From my own experience: international sockets are extremely rare, some in hotel bathrooms but only enough wattage for a mobile charger, not for a laptop. Alas,  a power adapter is necessary. These days there are very small [adapters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76696/4188) but that's a different [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4031/4188).

Comment: The hotel bathroom ones are intended for shavers/electric toothbrushes, I think, which would explain why they're not able to cope with a laptop.

Comment: No need to be surreptitious. There are some seating areas with sockets specifically for this purpose. http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-services/internet-and-wifi/

Comment: You can insert a European plug into a UK one with the help of any thin object, e.g. a key.

Comment: You can but it's not recommended. Firstly the UK uses relatively high-current socket circuits and compensates for this by fusing the plugs. Secondly there are mechanical compatibility issues, Europlugs can get caught on the sides of the holes while schuko plugs are too big to fit without a lot of force. Thirdly this trick won't work on MK sockets.

Answer (score 3):

I took this photo at Starbucks, Gatwick North Terminal, after security, waiting for Gate.

[image: starbucks]

---

This photo is at Pret A Manger, Gatwick North Terminal, near Gates 105-106

[image: pret]

Comment: That's a very nice hat!

Comment: @MadHatter  LOL :D